# Travelling with codeine to the US?

Tags: usa

I'm going to Los Angeles in the summer and the flight is 11 hours long. I can't bear such a long flight so I thought of taking a sleeping aid with me that has worked in the past.

Even though codeine is available here OTC, I've read that it is scheduled as a narcotic in the States and thus I would require a prescription. The thing is however some of my friends have brought codeine based medicines with them before and they weren't stopped.

Will it be an issue?

Comment: Codeine is listed as a schedule 2 narcotic https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/schedules/orangebook/c_cs_alpha.pdf#7 Your friends might have got away with it - did they declare they had the medicines on arrival? Were their belongings searched http://www.fda.gov/consumers/consumer-updates/5-tips-traveling-us-medications

Comment: @Traveller I don't think OP is bringing pure codeine as sleeping aid... Many/Most OTC-available codeine preparations are schedule V. Although this doesn't exempt OP's obligations to declare and perhaps holding a doctor's note/prescription, the consequence is different.